# exclude expressions within a set of characters

Tags: regex, preg-match

how can I write a regexp that matches any of these characters

```
[a-z.' ]
```

but excluding this expression

```
(?:bl(?: |\. |\.)ah)
```

?

the expression may appear {0,} times, at the start of the string, in the middle, or at the end

Comment: Doing this with a single expression would be really complicated .. you could just use `strpos` to match the single characters

Comment: So it's `bl ah`, `bl. ah`, `bl.ah` and `blah` you're tring to avoid? Also, which language are you using?

Comment: @inhan it's just an example...

Comment: Building a single pattern is possible but as this "example" changes the whole pattern will dramatically change. So it actually matters.

Comment: then pick, as example, the most easier expression (?:blah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*bl[. ]*ah)[a-z.' ]*
```

If you want to be pedantic about the maximum number of intervening chars within "blah":

```
 ^(?!.*bl[. ]{,2}ah)[a-z.' ]*
```

Comment: How would that match `AA`, `BLA` and `CC` in `AAbl ahbl.ahBLAbl. ahbl ahCC`?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing anything the following pattern should match. You might want to wrap "blah" with the boundary characters around -- `\bblah\b`

```
(?<=^|[^a-z.' ]|blah)(?:(?!blah)[a-z.' ])+
```

As with your main pattern (which needs to avoid `bl ah`, `bl. ah` and `bl.ah`) it would be

```
~
    (?<=^|[^a-z.' ]|bl[. ]ah|bl\.\ ah)
    (?:(?!bl(?:\ |\.\ ?)ah)[a-z.' ])+
~ix
```

Bad thing with lookbehinds are, you need to declare precise length. So you need to explicitly write what you want (or not) in the lookbehind.